# python regex use capture group to define another groups length { }

Tags: python, regex, hex

I am parsing streaming hex data with python regex. I have the following packet structure that I am trying to extract from the stream of packets:

```
'\xaa\x01\xFF\x44'
```

- \xaa - start of packet
- \x01 - data length [value can vary from 00-FF]
- \xFF - data
- \x44 - end of packet

i want to use python regex to indicate how much of the data portion of the packet to match as such:

```
r = re.compile('\xaa(?P<length>[\x00-\xFF]{1})(.*){?P<length>}\x44')
```

this compiles without errors, but it doesnt work.  I suspect it doesnt work because it the regex engine cannot convert the `<length>` named group hex value to an appropriate integer for use inside the regex `{}` expression.  Is there a method by which this can be accomplished in python without resorting to disseminating the match groups?

Background: I have been using erlang for packet unpacking and I was looking for something similar in python

Comment: If you're certain the packet structure at that point ends in `\x44`, can you get away with using `\xaa.(.*?)\x44`?  Or is there a chance that you'll encounter `\x44` within the payload of packets?

Comment: this is a streaming protocol running over a serial interface.  I may receive a read with more than 1 packet, or 1.5 packets etc.  With that in mind, I have to validate that what is matched is acutally the packet.  Just matching on the start and end block isnt enough as the data itself could include \xaa, \x44 bytes

Comment: In that case, I don't think regex is your answer.  I'd build something that used a `deque`, have new incoming packets extend it, and then a consumer that retrieved from it (potentially with some state-based parsing, depending on how complicated the incoming stream is).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up doing something as follows:

```
self.packet_regex = \
            re.compile('(\xaa)([\x04-\xFF]{1})([\x00-\xFF]{1})([\x10-\xFF]{1})([\x00-\xFF]*)([\x00-\xFF]{1})(\x44)')

match = self.packet_regex.search(self.buffer)
if match and match.groups():
    groups = match.groups()
    if (ord(groups[1]) - 4) == len(groups[4]) + len(groups[5]) + len(groups[6]):
        ...
```

Comment: This method seems to have some flaws; for example take the string `\xAA\x08\xFF\x22\xDA\x44\xEE\xFC\xAB\xAD\x44\xEE` - it returns `\xdaD\xee\xfc\xab`, even though the packet length is supposed to be 8. It wouldn't hurt to show the rest of your code also (after the last if statement).

Answer (score -1):

This is pretty much a work around for what you have asked. Just have a look at it

```
import re
orig_str = '\xaa\x01\xFF\x44'
print orig_str
#converting original hex data into its representation form
st = repr(orig_str)
print st
#getting the representation form of regex and removing leading and trailing single quotes 
reg = re.compile(repr("(\\xaa)")[1:-1])
p = reg.search(st)

#creating the representation from matched string by adding leading and trailing single quotes
extracted_repr = "\'"+p.group(1)+"\'"
print extracted_repr

#evaluating the matched string to get the original hex information
extracted_str = eval(extracted_repr)
print extracted_str

>>>
    ��D
    '\xaa\x01\xffD'
    '\xaa'
    �
```